# list view with (ado.net entity data model), i want to update list view when click the btn

Tags: wpf, xaml, ado.net

wpf c# side MainWindow call the yenikaytekle window to take the perperty,I i use the ado.net data model to fill the list view at xaml file.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillMarkaListView();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// fill the list view
    /// </summary>
    public void FillMarkaListView()
    {
        //get list of all marka
        List<MARKA> listOfMarka = dbContext.MARKA.ToList();
        lvMarka.ItemsSource = listOfMarka;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// add new item to marak table,with open new window to give marka name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnYeniMarkaEkle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //here open new window to take the details of model
        YeniMarkaEkle saveWindow = new YeniMarkaEkle();
        saveWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

the another window to take the details of model,here i call the window to take the property of model and save the data in database

```
 public partial class YeniMarkaEkle : Window
{
    private BaburTechEntities dbContext = new BaburTechEntities();
    public YeniMarkaEkle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtMarka.SelectAll();
        txtMarka.Focus();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// add new marka to the table
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnDialogOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MARKA mARKA = new MARKA();
        mARKA.ADI = txtMarka.Text.ToUpper();

        dbContext.MARKA.Add(mARKA);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        this.Close();

    }
}
```

here is my main window xaml code

```
 <!-- List of marka-->
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
                            <Grid>
                                <ListView Margin="10" x:Name="lvMarka" >
                                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <ListView.View>
                                        <GridView>
                                            <GridViewColumn Header="Kategori ID" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
                                            <GridViewColumn Header="Kategori" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ADI}" />
                                        </GridView>
                                    </ListView.View>
                                </ListView>
                            </Grid>

                        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I can't really get what you are trying to get here. Please try to explain yourself a lil' bit better :) You want your "btnDialogOk_Click" from YeniMarkaEkle class to update your MainWindow ListView ?

Comment: yes,i know i have to use the INotifyPropertyChanged but i can't use it with my model,

Comment: i want when the YeniMarkaEkle window closed, my list view at the MainWindow update

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your updated list you should call `dbContext.MARKA.ToList()` again after you call `saveWindow.ShowDialog();` and set it to your listView itemssource but you should read about MVVM because what you are doing here doesn't follow good practices.

EDIT:

```
private List<MARKA> listOfMarka

    public MainWindow()
{
    listOfMarka= new List<MARKA>();
    InitializeComponent();
    FillMarkaListView();
}
private List<MARKA> listOfMarka
/// <summary>
/// fill the list view
/// </summary>
public void FillMarkaListView()
{
    //get list of all marka
    listOfMarka = dbContext.MARKA.ToList();
    lvMarka.ItemsSource = listOfMarka;
}

/// <summary>
/// add new item to marak table,with open new window to give marka name
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void btnYeniMarkaEkle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //here open new window to take the details of model
    YeniMarkaEkle saveWindow = new YeniMarkaEkle(listOfMarka);
    saveWindow.ShowDialog();
    lvMarka.ItemsSource = listOfMarka;
}


public partial class YeniMarkaEkle : Window
{
private BaburTechEntities dbContext = new BaburTechEntities();
private List<MARKA> listOfMarka;

public YeniMarkaEkle(List<MARKA> listOfMarka)
{
    listOfMarka = listOfMarka;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtMarka.SelectAll();
    txtMarka.Focus();
}

/// <summary>
/// add new marka to the table
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void btnDialogOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MARKA mARKA = new MARKA();
    mARKA.ADI = txtMarka.Text.ToUpper();
    listOfMarka.Add(mARKA);
    dbContext.MARKA.Add(mARKA);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    this.Close();

}
```

Comment: yes i know but i am new in wpf,thank you for your interest

Comment: Check my answer and try it. If it helped you remember to upvote it and mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Check my new edit. You can pass your list to the "new" window and update it, then when you come from the new window just set it to be te ListView ItemsSource

Comment: it's work first time but not working if you try to save new item,my coding is not good i need learn about the mvvm,thank you

Comment: Copy the code below the "EDIT", it should work for you.

Comment: yes its work for first time clean the list you can see just new item and after the first time when you click for save item its save but does not show at the list view

Comment: for see the all of list view item i have to close and open again the window,but i want its reload  automatically, like Ajax in the MVC  :-o

Comment: Put this `lvMarka.Items.Refresh();` after your `lvMarka.ItemsSource = listOfMarka;` in your `btnYeniMarkaEkle_Click` it should work then

Comment: i edit my code like what you say but again its work behinde does not show every list item , i need to edit base my code and use MVVM mothod thank you for your answers.